# Idea for 404 error

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I saw on a website somewhere that whenever there was some kind of error, it turned into a game of space invaders or some other arcade game, using the letters "ERROR 404" as the blocks that would break. Just thought it would be cool since:

1. saw it on Vsauce(3?) on youtube.
2. It would be perfect since this is "arqade", it would be a fitting thing! Not to mention, something entertaining if there is an error, so its more of an encouragement rather than a disappointment!

Another thing, perhaps if there is a 403 (security exception), Just a simple little "hacking gui" with username and password box that has some little joke for an award for cracking it, but there is no real username and password. A joke. For the hackers, and the ones who just stumbled upon it.

ERROR 403:

username:(enter)
   Password:(*****enter)

You crack this and you get a free book! (retail value of $100+)

*click!

Oh , so close! Guess you don't get your free [Justin Bieber] Book (with poster included). Try Again!

:P

Comment: I do feel like, out of all of the places on Arqade to have downvotes without comments, that Meta is the worst of them. People who come to Meta have at least a pointed interest in the health and community behind Arqade, otherwise they would not even be here. Questions with ~10 downvotes and no comments are not only discouraging to the user in Arqade, but specifically in Meta.

Comment: @Mondrianaire I'm fairly certain this question used to have lots of comments that were, when the issue was resolved, removed (as it is supposed to be).

Comment: @FEichinger There are no deleted comments on this post. That said, downvotes on the main site usually mean, "This content is poor". Downvotes on the meta site simply mean, "I Disagree". While I understanding that getting downvotes (on Meta, or anywhere), is an ill-loved experience, "I don't feel a need for this feature" should not be interpreted as, "your post is bad, and you should feel bad".

Answer (score 3):

We already have a site-specific 404 Image, that of a nearly empty life bar:

[image]

If you're looking for a game-y Easter Egg (on this, a Games site), you might try joining chat and typing, "insert coin".

Comment: Note: You will need 20 rep in order to chat